# Will Angular 12 supports @ng-toolkit/universal and allow for serverless deployment?

Tags: angular, serverless, angular-universal

SCENARIO: I am working in angular 12 sample project and to deploy in AWS lambda serverless environment.
To make this done, I am using the following steps.

I tried to install `@ng-toolkit/universal` without mentioning the version using the command ng add **`@ng-toolkit/universal`**.

It started installing the packages of version 1.1.21 , without creating the necessary files such as

- server.module.ts
- broswer.module.ts
- etc....

So I tried with mentioning the versions that is the latest one such as 8.1.0 and the other versions in 7.

It doesn't get installed leaving the error.

Next, I tried with the lower version 1.1.45, it shows the error as follows:

> No matching version found for @nguniversal/express-engine@~12.2.0.

To fix this I installed `@nguniversal/express-engine@next` .

Next run the application using `ng serve`, It ran successfully as expected.

When I tried to build using the `npm run build:prod` command, it shows the following error

```
./src/app/app.server.module.ts:8:26-61 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-server' in 'C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\universal12\testing\src\app'

./src/app/app.server.module.ts:9:38-89 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader' in 'C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\universal12\testing\src\app'

Error: src/app/app.server.module.ts:4:59 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-server' or its corresponding type declarations.

4     import {ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule} from '@angular/platform-server';
                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/app.server.module.ts:5:41 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader' or its corresponding type declarations.

5     import {ModuleMapLoaderModule} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/app.server.module.ts:12:17 - error NG1010: Value at position 2 in the NgModule.imports of AppServerModule is not a reference  Value could not be determined statically.

 12         imports:[
                    ~
 13  BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'app-root'}),
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 20             ServerTransferStateModule, // comment
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 21         ]
    ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.server.module.ts:17:13
    17             ServerModule,
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Unknown reference.



npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! testing@0.0.0 build:server:prod: `ng run testing:server && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the testing@0.0.0 build:server:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-14T13_35_09_112Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! testing@0.0.0 build:prod: `npm run build:server:prod && npm run build:browser:prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the testing@0.0.0 build:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-14T13_35_09_216Z-debug.log
```

To fix the above issues I added the packages `@angular/platform-server` and `@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@next`.

Then once again I tried to create a build of the project.

It asked for the installation of `**webpack-cli**` , I also grant permission to download it.

After installation of **`webpack-cli`**, it shows the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined
    at module.exports (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\universal12\testing\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\config-yargs.js:89:48)
    at C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\universal12\testing\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:60:27
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\universal12\testing\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:515:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at runCli (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\universal12\testing\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:69:2)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! testing@0.0.0 build:server:prod: `ng run testing:server && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the testing@0.0.0 build:server:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-14T13_46_01_270Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! testing@0.0.0 build:prod: `npm run build:server:prod && npm run build:browser:prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the testing@0.0.0 build:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-14T13_46_01_461Z-debug.log
```

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "build:server:prod": "ng run testing:server && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "build:browser:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "build:prod": "npm run build:server:prod && npm run build:browser:prod",
    "server": "node local.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^1.1.45",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^12.1.0-next.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^9.0.0-next.9",
    "cors": "~2.8.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "ts-loader": "4.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.5"
  }
}
```

What is the solution for the issue?

Else someone can also suggest some another way of achieving the goal of serverless deployment using the `@ng-toolkit/universal` and `@ng-toolkit/serverless` importantly in the angular version 12.

Answer (score 0):

The version of your @ng-toolkit/universal is 3 years old https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-toolkit/universal?activeTab=versions. The latest version is **8.1.0**, still quite old but works with Angular 12 in my project.
This version depends on **@nguniversal/express-engine@12.1.1**. If you are using an enterprise repository, e.g. Nexus, make sure this version exists there.